# How to compile and version assets in Laravel elixir?

Tags: php, gulp, laravel-elixir

At this moment I want to configure my assets for project. My Gulp file looks:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(mix => {
   mix.sass('app.scss');
   .webpack('app.js');
});
```

But I want to turn on version for my css files. But existing info says to use:

```
mix.version('css/app.css'); // public/build/css/app-39d5f9a7.css
```

I don't know where I lost here, but I do not know the right way how to make this to work. I want to compile my .sass files and give then a version. I would like to use

```
<link src='{{ elexir('css/app.css') }}'>
```

in my layout.blade.php 
How to do it right?

Comment: Can you show what you're gulp file looked like after you added  `mix.version` to it?

Comment: mix.sass('app.scss').
version('css/app.css').
webpack('app.js');
But I don't know does it work...

Comment: Try putting version at the bottom of the block. Also, make sure you're not watching for these changes (`gulp watch`) as they won't be actioned unless you restart the watcher.

Comment: I am getting syntax error. How can I simplify that  'mix' array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because you're ending the statements instead of chaining them. You would either need to remove the `;`s (apart from the last one) or add mix to the beginning of each method call.

Change your gulp file to be:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
        .webpack('app.js')
        .version('css/app.css');
});
```

Also, you should change:

```
<link src='{{ elexir('css/app.css') }}'>
```

to be:

```
<link href='{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}'>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still not getting expected result.
 public/build/css/app-39d5f9a7.css file isn't created after running gulp, but no syntax errors now.

Comment: @pvaitonis Does a file exist at `public/css/app.css`? If so, delete the css folder, run gulp and double check that it is definitely getting generated.

Comment: yes, file is generated, but seems versioning isn't working.

Comment: So you don't have a file at `public/build/css/app-[some-hash].css`. If the file does exist then check the edit to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't have file public/build/css/app-[some-hash].css after running gulp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131722/discussion-between-pvaitonis-and-ross-wilson).